# Weird error when attempting to parse topicDetails from listChannels

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

when using the youtube data api the json returned from list channel will parse statistics but not topicDetails. Below is my basic code to return data.

```
$part ='topicDetails,statistics';    
$response = $service->channels->listChannels($part,$channel_id); 
$topic = $response->items[0];
return $topic;
```

this returns

```
[statistics] => Array
            (
                [viewCount] => 230769010
                [commentCount] => 92
                [subscriberCount] => 1540335
                [hiddenSubscriberCount] => 
                [videoCount] => 526
            )

        [topicDetails] => Array
            (
                [topicIds] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => /m/02vxn
                        [1] => /m/02jjt
                        [2] => /m/019_rr
                        [3] => /m/03glg
                        [4] => /m/02vxn
                    )
```

The code below parses the json for statistics, and works fine

```
$response = $service->channels->listChannels($part,$channel_id); 
$topic = $response->items[0]->statistics;
return $topic;
```

[The code above returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Ktx.png)
This is where is gets weird. The code below should parse topicDetails but errors.

```
$response = $service->channels->listChannels($part,$channel_id); 
$topic = $response->items[0]->topicDetails;
return $topic;
```

This is the error i get when trying to parse for topicDetails
[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c6fh.png)

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated. The same code worked a few days ago. Perhaps youtube api changed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are encountering the same issue right now.

EDIT*** SOLUTION

I believe youtube changed the returned object from the api call to include ['modelData'] which is protected so you must index it.

Set your return response to

```
$response['items'][0];
```

Then in the file you call the function set whatever variable to the response:

```
$channel_info=youtubeFunctionName(params);
```

Then you have to now parse index ['modelData'] in order to get topic details.

```
$channel_info=$channel_info['modelData']['topicDetails']['topicIds']
```

Now what doesn't make sense is why you are able to pull ['statistics'] without indexing ['modelData']. Hopefully youtube provides documentation on the changes.